# How to rewrite www to non www in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I found a couple of other serverfault questions where rewrite www to non-www in nginx was answered, however it seems like with the nginx config my webdock.io server has the solutions I have tried seem to always cause problems or simply don't work. I suspect it has to do with the order or a conflict with what is already there.

Here is the current config

```
server {

root /var/www/html;
client_max_body_size 256M;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.php;

#Which domain names will this vhost respond to
server_name my-clients-domain.com www.my-clients-domain.com;

location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
access_log /var/www/logs/access.log;
error_log  /var/www/logs/error.log error;
error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
  add_header X-Powered-By "Webdock.io";
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
  fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
}

# Necessary for Let's Encrypt Domain Name ownership validation. Place any other deny rules after this
location ~ /.well-known {
allow all;
}

# Deny access to .htaccess or .htpasswd files
location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}

    # Deny access to any git repository
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
    }

    # Deny access to xmlrpc.php - a common brute force target against Wordpress
    location = /xmlrpc.php {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        return 444;
    }

    # Webdock: Do not delete the following End Of File marker if editing this file by hand
    #EOWDSLBLK

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-clients-domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-clients-domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server { if ($host = www.my-clients-domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = my-clients-domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name my-clients-domain.com  www.my-clients-domain.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I am wanting all `https://www.my-clients-domain.com` to rewrite to `https://my-clients-domain.com`

I have tried adding the following server block at different points in the config file but each time it either does not work as expected.

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; 
    listen 443 ssl; 

    server_name www.my-clients-domain.com;
    return 301 https://my-clients-domain.com$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-clients-domain.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-clients-domain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 
}
```

If I type enter `https://www.my-clients-domain.com`  the "www" remains in the url.  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware that a 301 is intended to be a permanent and should be cached by your browser. When testing a change in your configuration: after reloading the nginx configuration  test from a new private/incognito browser window.

---

> I am wanting all `https://www.my-clients-domain.com` to rewrite to `https://my-clients-domain.com`

Then I would for starters ensure that when you redirect from plain HTTP to HTTPS, that your visitors immediately get redirected to `https://my-clients-domain.com`  and don't get redirected first from `http://www.my-clients-domain.com` to `https://www.my-clients-domain.com` where the immediately  get  a second redirect to `https://my-clients-domain.com`

Rather than a redirect with a `$host` parameter use the desired domain and have a concise:

```
server { 
        listen 80; 
        server_name my-clients-domain.com  www.my-clients-domain.com;
        return 301 https://my-clients-domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Your SSL server block looks OK already.

I would expect a second block for the bare domain, that holds your web content: (Assuming that the certificate `/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-clients-domain.com/` is also valid for `www.my-clients-domain.com` )

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; 
    listen 443 ssl; 

    server_name www.my-clients-domain.com;
    return 301 https://my-clients-domain.com$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-clients-domain.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-clients-domain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 
}
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; 
    listen 443 ssl; 

    server_name my-clients-domain.com;
    root  /var/www/default/htdocs;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-clients-domain.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-clients-domain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 
}
```

Or slightly more concise:

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; 
    listen 443 ssl; 

    server_name my-clients-domain.com www.my-clients-domain.com;
    root  /var/www/default/htdocs;

    if ($host = www.my-clients-domain.com) {
       return 301 https://my-clients-domain.com$request_uri;
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-clients-domain.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-clients-domain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 
}
```

Comment: Great Thanks a million!